# Box WebApp Integration get parent details of a selected file

Tags: javascript, box-api, box

Using a Box filepicker in my web app. Configured as below:

In my HTML, added:

```
<script src="https://app.box.com/js/static/select.js"></script>
```

and in JS file,

```
var options = {
  clientId: myClientID,
  linkType: 'shared',
  multiselect: 'true'
};
var boxSelect = new BoxSelect(options);

// Register a success callback handler
boxSelect.success(function(response) {
  console.log(response[0].id); //This is giving me the fileId of a selected file
  console.log(response[0].id.parentNode); //Tried this to get parent (folder name associated to the selected file and gets undefined)
});
// Register a cancel callback handler
boxSelect.cancel(function() {
  console.log("The user clicked cancel or closed the popup");
});

$scope.launchBoxFilePicker = function() {
  boxSelect.launchPopup();
};
```

Can any one of you guide me on how to get the parent details of a selected file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design the parent details of a file are not exposed via the Box File Picker.